# Converting tuple into records in blank feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

Here is the code block that I am using with ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop, it all works great except for the bottom part. I am not sure how to turn the tuple into records on a blank feature class. The tuple looks like this: ('BRONTE DR', 'BRONTE DR', 'RICHARDSON DR', 'RICHARDSON DR'). I want each part of the tuple to be a new record in the blank feature class.

```
import re
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
if arcpy.Exists(r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb\street_assets2"):
    arcpy.Delete_management(r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb\street_assets2")
arcpy.env.workspace = r'J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb'
table1 = r"street_assets"
field1 = r"STREET_OR_INTERSECTION"
def unique_values(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})
newtuple = unique_values(table1,field1)
newtuple = str(newtuple)
newtuple = newtuple.split("}{")
newtuple = ([s.replace('\'', '') for s in newtuple])
newtuple = ([s.replace('"', '') for s in newtuple])
newtuple = ([s.replace('u', '') for s in newtuple])
newtuple = ([s.replace('[', '') for s in newtuple])
newtuple = ([s.replace(']', '') for s in newtuple])
newtuple = ([s.replace('{', '') for s in newtuple])
newtuple = ([s.replace('}', '') for s in newtuple])
out_path = r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb"
out_name = "street_assets2"
geometry_type = "POINT"
template = r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb\street_assets"
has_m = "DISABLED"
has_z = "DISABLED"
spatial_reference = arcpy.Describe(r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb\street_assets").spatialReference
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type, template, has_m, has_z, spatial_reference)
newtuple = tuple(newtuple)
print newtuple

## Problem Here


cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb\street_assets2", ['STREET_OR_INTERSECTION'])
i = 0
for i in newtuple:
    cursor.insertRow([i])
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with cursors, each row is a tuple. In your case, you need to create a tuple with one value.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r"J:\STW\Divisions_&_Branches\MSMD\Branches_&_Sections\GIS\users\Anault\intersections_software_development\OUTPUT.gdb\street_assets2", ['STREET_OR_INTERSECTION'])
for i in newtuple:
    #create tuple with one value
    row = (i,)
    cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```